# How to output the custom date on bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using a [bootstrap datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#input) and i want to show the result in week date format e.g 02-05-2015 - 10-05-2015 (dd-mm-yyyy)

```
      <input style="margin-top:5px" class="form-control datepicker" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            minViewMode: '0',
            language: "vi",
            autoclose: true,
            selectWeek: true,
            todayHighlight: true

        }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
            var date = e.date;
            var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);

            var endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 7);

           // how to output the custom date with the format 8-6-2015 - 14-6-2015

// i even try $('.datepicker').text('abc') but then it ruins the whole system
            console.log(startDate.toJSON());
            console.log(endDate);
            console.log(e);
        })
    </script>
```

I expect to get the output result just like http://www.tikalk.com/incubator/week-picker-using-jquery-ui-datepicker/ (whole week select) right in the input control.

The whole code is [here on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NctGxJgI34hoZsIWcSb9?p=preview)

Comment: try startDate.toJSON().substring(0,10) but this doesn't give the desired format. you can try the jquery dateFormat plugin https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: sorry no being clear, my question is how to output the whole week to the input, not how to format a date.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Misunderstood your question. When you said "week format" you meant you wanted a week range.

Two options I can see.

1. Easy: Label the field "Week of:" and use `daysOfWeekDisabled` attribute when initiating datepicker to only allow Sun/Mon (depending on when your week starts)

   ```
   $('input').datepicker({
       daysOfWeekDisabled: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
   });
   ```

   would disable Mon through Sat.
2. Complicated: Use the [date-range](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#date-range) markup, [hide](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#hide) event, and `.getDay()` to change the values in the input based upon day of the week. Something like this would work, but I haven't tested this at all.

   ```
   $('input.startofweek').datepicker({
       format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
   }).on('hide',function( e ) {
       //probably best to create named functions rather than this
       var nd = e.date;
       if (nd.getDay() !== 0) {
           nd.setDate(nd.getDate()-nd.getDay());
           $(this).datepicker('update',nd);
       }
   });

   $('input.endofweek').datepicker({
       format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
   }).on('hide',function( e ) {
       if (nd.getDay() !== 6) {
           nd.setDate(nd.getDate()+(6-nd.getDay()));
           $(this).datepicker('update',nd);
       }
   });
   ```

   If you prefer to continue using `multidate` that would require something similar but different markup.

Comment: Hi, what I need is how to show on the input the text  for the whole week,  the format is not important. I just can't find a way to set the custom text, somehow in Angularjs I can do it using the same datepicker component